# Video card wrong output frequency

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, external-display

I have a Zenbook notebook with a GeForce GTX950M and I use an external monitor HP 24es.

Sometimes the image displayed is resized to half screen. This behaviour is complex to explain so I [attach an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxidA.jpg).

This problem appers frequently when I use Lightroom or when I play a game (whatchdog for example).

The only way to return to a normal situation is to un-plug the HDMI cable and replug it. After that the behaviour seems normal but after few minutes the screen is resized again.

Furtermore sometimes, the external monitor shows a warning message about the sync frequency:

- Current mode: H:70.7 kHz and V = 62 Hz
- Current mode: 1920 x 1080 - 60 Hz

I checked the Output frequency and it is set to 60Hz.
[This image shows the monitor warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G94f5.jpg)

The video driver is Updated to the lates version.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Can somebody help me? I don't know how to solve this problem.

I want to avoid to send the pc to the repair center.

Please note that this problem happen only with the external monitor. With the integrated display everything works"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Assuming you have the correct graphics drivers installed and knowing it only happens with the external monitor, try another monitor if available. It's unlikely to be a problem with the notebook itself.

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI cable?